# How to redirect specific links to https:// everything else to http:// using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl

I am trying to use htaccess to automatically direct all requests to certain pages to https and everything else to http://

Here is the code I've got the code to force ssl working below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^va-homebuyers-guide https://domain.com/va-homebuyers-guide/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^va-purchase-request https://domain.com/va-purchase-request/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^va-streamline-refinance https://domain.com/va-streamline-refinance/ [R=301,L]
```

This is working as expected and redirects to the ssl versions of those pages. I then tried adding the following to redirect everything else to http:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^va-homebuyers-guide$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^va-purchase-request$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^va-streamline-refinance$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This code results in a redirect loop when going to /va-purchase-request /va-homebuyers-guide and /va-streamline-refinance and does not redirect the other pages at all.

I'm totally stuck with this and any help would be massively appreciated!

Edit:

I also have this code in the .htaccess file added by wordpress... Could it be interfering with the other redirects?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

# END WordPress

Comment: Check [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/28395/11628). (What you're trying to do is probably partly insecure...)

Answer (score 1):

Replace your .htaccess code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^va-(homebuyers-guide|purchase-request|streamline-refinance)(/.*|)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (?!^va-(homebuyers-guide|purchase-request|streamline-refinance)(/.*|)$)^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: This is working to redirect everything else back to http: however, when I go to one of the pages which is supposed to redirect, I get sent to the homepage(http://domain.com) any ideas?

Comment: Sorry didn't get you. What URI did you try that didn't work? Any chance that there is some redirection somewhere else as well like another .htaccess code or inside the code?

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me... 

The urls https://domain.com/va-homebuyers-guide/ https://domain.com/va-purchase-request/ and https://domain.com/va-streamline-refinance/ are all directing to http://domain.com when I use your code. 

There is some other redirection in the file added by wordpress which is as follows and is directly below the code you gave me

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Edited the original result adding the wordpress code for clarity

Comment: Ah didn't realize Wordpress was also in scene. WP redirect rule is definitely interfering here specifically this one `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`. Is `domain.com/va-homebuyers-guide` also WP served page or outside WP?

Comment: It's served by wordpress. Thanks so much for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I will need to be offline now, will be back after few hours. In the meantime I suggest you to pls check 2 plugins: [wpssl](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpssl/) and [wordpress-https](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/faq/). Aditionally check [this faq](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129/is-there-a-way-to-force-ssl-on-certain-pages).